# Using Kendo Dataviz Vertical Bullet Graph, How to add labels similar to Bar Graph?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dataviz, bullet-chart

Trying to Style up the Bullet Graph to be exactly as Marketing desires. The desired Graph looks like:

[image]

How do you add the labels at the top of the bars?

I've tried to set the labels property from the Kendo Documentation:

```
 labels:
 {
visible: true,
format: "{0}",
font: "14px Arial",
 },
```

Here is my script that isn't working:

```
        $barChart = $("#bar-chart").empty();

         $barChart.kendoChart({
            theme: global.app.chartsTheme,
            renderAs: "svg",
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column"
            },
            series: [
                {   
                    type: "verticalBullet",
                    currentField: "score",
                    targetField: "average",
                    target: {
                        color: "#444",
                        dashType: "dot",
                        line: {
                          width: 1,
                        }
                    },
                    labels:
                    {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}",
                        font: "14px Arial",
                    },
                    data: [
                       {
                            score: 93.7,
                            average: 65.2,                              
                        }, {
                            score: 80.2,
                            average: 22.2,
                        }, {
                            score: 60.8,
                            average: 35.2,
                        }, {

                            score: 82.1,
                            average: 45.2,                                
                        }, {
                            score: 74.2,
                            average: 55.2,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            categoryAxis: {
                labels: { rotation: -45 },
                categories: ["Sales & Contracting", "Implementation & Training", "Functionality & Upgrades", "Service & Support", "General"],
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                color: "#444", 
                axisCrossingValue: [0, 0, 100, 100]
            },
             tooltip: {
                visible: false
            }
        }).data("kendoChart");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not a supported feature, any attempt to do this is by it's nature a hack. I had a look at kendo demo and noticed that there is a tooltip element with class k-tooltip that contains the total for a bar on mouseover. You should take a look into that mouseover to display the totals.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, however I'm using this on a mobile app and mouse over doesn't work that well on Mobile.

Comment: @Rodney you can get the code from the mouse over and make it display by default without the event.

Comment: do you have an example of this in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is possible. I've created an example on our Try Kendo UI site here: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@jbristowe/aDIf/7

Comment: I think this actually ends up being a normal bar chart, not a bullet chart... Try using the bullet-specific features, like drawing a line, and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To recap, bullet charts don't support that type of label you need, and bar charts don't support the visual you need (the special line on the chart).

You could switch back to bar charts and write a custom visual. However, an easier way is to use a plotband on the value axis: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/valueaxis.plotbands

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  valueAxis:  {
    plotBands: [
      { from: 1, to: 2, color: "red" }
    ]
  },
  series: [
    { data: [1, 2, 3] }
  ]
});
</script>
```

If you make a very narrow band, it will work pretty. It won't be dotted as in your reference image, and it will be *behind* the bar, which might be a problem... To go deeper, you would need a custom visual, and it's going to be involved: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.visual